# Subscriptions depending addressfield field

Tags: location, entities, notifications

I have a events web page based on Drupal 7.Each of the events has a adressfield field.

Now I need add a subscriptions functionality. I need each user can subscribe to the events taking place in one city (or one country).

I think none of the contributed modules can manage that.

Comment: Like groups.drupal.org operate ?

Comment: I don't know if drupal groups can filter by location. For example a user suscribes to London events, and every time someone add a event taking place in London he will receive a email. He won't receive email if the event added is taking place in New York.

Comment: I am thinking to write a custom module implementing hook_mail(). Is It a correct way??