# Subscription to User-saved searches

Tags: 7, rules, notifications

Required functionality:

- User can filter nodes based on certain relevant custom fields.
- User can save filter criteria as a named set.
- User can view and edit these sets of filter criteria.
- User can "subscribe" to changes based on his saved sets of filter criteria and get email notifications containing links to only the newly matching nodes.

Can I build such subscriptions with mostly out-of-the-box functionality of Rules and related modules?

[Subscriptions depending addressfield field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81476/subscriptions-depending-addressfield-field) is a related question, but the poor lad did not get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually the business logic you want to complete is possible using Drupal. Finding a way to make this scale to a very large website -- I leave as a project for you.

Start by looking at [Saved Searches](https://www.drupal.org/project/savedsearches) and [Views Saved Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_savedsearches) or [Views Save](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_save). These modules let you save a search with a simple name for later re-use. Some of these modules allow per-user saved searches.

You could then create a Queue using the [Queue API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7) in Drupal to periodically process the resultsets of these searches. Or even use the [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module to store heuristics on these resultsets.

Create a cron task using `hook_cron` or Rules Scheduler to periodically process the resultsets and have Rules to send off emails about new changes in the saved searches. Functions like `views_get_results` (if you use views_saved_searches) can help you to get these results.

So in general yes it's possible with Drupal -- scaling all this to a very large amount of  users is either an infrastructure problem or something (i think) "Drupal" shouldn't do in the long run ...

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Saved Searches is not available for 7 and does not appear to be actively maintained. But you got me on the right path - this https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_saved_searches looks very promising.